# In spring why the interface is injected?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In spring why the interface is injected rather than the class implementing the interface?

Comment: An interface is never injected.

Comment: See LID of [SOLID](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact even if you use interface a class is injected. Spring looks for a bean - class which implements the interface.

In some cases like e.g. Spring Data dynamic proxy is created for the interfaces which in fact a class to listen interface's methods calls and do some logic on the calls.

If you set a breakpoint and check what is really injected you will find a class (either your class or some Proxy object)